# Is it possible to unload data in AWS Athena to a single file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

The [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unload.html) states that

> UNLOAD results are written to multiple files in parallel.

I guess this is more efficient for both read and write, so unloading to a single file doesn't make sense.  But, if for some reason the end user wants the output as a single file, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running a `SELECT` query in `Athena` produces a single result file in `Amazon S3` in uncompressed CSV format this is the default behaviour.

If your query is expected to output a large result set then significant time is spent in writing results as one single file to Amazon S3. With `UNLOAD`, you can split the results into multiple files in Amazon S3, which reduces the time spent in the writing phase hence better performance and you can even use compression techniques like `parquet`.

What you are trying to do is not what unload is meant for. One solution would be to write some kind of post processor which will merge the files after the write is finished. Maybe using the `lambda` function which is triggered on S3 write.

Comment: uggly operators

Answer (score 5):

You can trick Athena to produce a single large result file for `CTAS` queries by specifying a single bucketing column that has a constant value and setting

```
bucket_count = 1
```

This can generate very large single files with formats other than `CSV`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for UNLOAD commands

Comment: I discovered this trick prior to UNLOAD functionality being available. You can easily achieve what you want by executing CREATE TABLE AS ... followed by DROP - data remains in S3 and this is essentially equivalent to UNLOAD with some minimal charges for Glue calls to CREATE/DROP table.

Answer (score 4):

Assumed your UNLOAD query is using `TEXTFILE` format and `gzip` compression like:

```
UNLOAD( select * from my_table ) 
TO 's3://your_bucket/your_path/'
WITH (
    format = 'TEXTFILE',
    compression = 'gzip',
    field_delimiter = '\t'
)
```

A simple solution would be the following:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://your_bucket/your_path/ .
gzip -d *
cat * > your_file.csv
```

Comment: So, this would create a compressed flat file, right?

Comment: @DGenchev yes, but if you prefer to be text, just remove compression in the UNLOAD and the gzip command afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. What about writing to a single ORC/Parquet file? Is that even an option?

Comment: Unload is multi-file, but it looks like they address this with the second half, decompress and combine in command line. I'm not seeing away around this, other then locating your Athena query results location and identifying your query ID.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unload.html